# Batch processing 10 records java , JPA

Tags: java, jpa, batch-processing

I am trying to fetch10 records at a time . The problem is the code just fetches first 10 records and last 4 records. It skips the in-between 10 records.
Considering that DB has 24 records in the table. The following program should fetch 24 records

SelectQuery: SELECT l FROM Object l where l.processed='N'
fetchObjectsCount query : Select count(*) from Object obj where l.processed='N'

```
   private static Integer MAX_RESULT = 10;
     private DataExtraction objectExtraction(){
        int count = leadRepo.fetchObjectsCount();
        Query query = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
          if (i % MAX_RESULT == 0 ){
           query=entityManager.createNamedQuery("SelectQuery").setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(MAX_RESULT);
           List<Object> tempList = (List<Object>) query.getResultList();
           entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

           for (Object ob : tempList){
              ob .setProcessed("Y");
              entityManager.persist(ob );                   
             }
             entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
             i = i+9;
        }

        if (i % MAX_RESULT < 1 && count - i <= MAX_RESULT){
        query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("SelectQuery").setFirstResult(i).setMaxResults(count-i);
        List<Object> tempList = (List<Object>) query.getResultList();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        for (Object ob : tempList){
        ob .setProcessed("Y");
        entityManager.persist(ob );                 
        }

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
      }
     }
     return this;

     }
```

Comment: Please accept my edit of your code, it is badly needed

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're fetching 10 at a time and you have 24 items in the db that code will only fetch two out of the required 3 times.

First iteration: retrieve 10 rows, i is set to 10 
Second iteration: retrieve 10 rows, i is set to > 10
Third iteration: won't happen

Here is how I would go about this:

```
int count = leadRepo.fetchObjectsCount();
int numberProcessed = 0;
Integer MAX_RESULT = 10;
query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("SelectQuery");


while(numberProcessed < count) {

    query.setFirstResult(numberProcessed).setMaxResults(MAX_RESULT);
    List<Object> tempList = (List<Object>) query.getResultList();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    for (Object ob : tempList) {
        ob.setProcessed("Y");
        entityManager.merge(ob);  
    }

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    objectList.addAll(tempList);
    numberProcessed += tempList.size();
}
```

This code assumes that you want to process all rows retrieved. If your named query is pulling out a different number of rows than fetchObjectsCount(); this should be written differently.

Comment: Your code has too many iterations. and still fetches the same 14 records and skips the in between 10 records.

Comment: . I think I cant update the status ("Y") which I am trying to do after fetching.

Comment: How many iterations does it have, and what query are you actually running with that named query?

Comment: should also be entityManager.merge() instead of persist();

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're processing the first ten records on your first iteration (because 0 % 10 == 0), then at the bottom of that loop you're incrementing i by 9. The loops starts again, incrementing i to 10, which again triggers the record processing loop. Now you're selecting the unprocessed records (only 14 now, since you've updated the first ten), skipping the first ten, and getting the last four. You might try starting your loop with 1 and see if that gives the results you expect.

Comment: yeah I advised him to NOT instantiate the query every iteration. I'm not certain but that seems like a good way to generate a new query every iteration, where what you've described here would happen.

Comment: I tried starting my loop with 1 but it still gives the same results. I wonder how can i fetch 10 records and then update it and then get the next 10 results.